# Creating a four dimensional system to find a point

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

How can I create a four-dimensional system that has a solution of $(-2,5,-6,1)$?

I know how to solve a system for its solution, but how do I work backwards?

Comment: Are there any constraints on the system so that you can't just say $x_1 = -2, x_2 = 5, x_3 = -6, x_4 = 1$?

Comment: Do you require that that solution be unique?

Comment: No there are no constraints, but considering this is a pre-uni question I'd appreciate if I could get both that standard answer and a more complicated one, since in uni they won't baby me like that.